# OpenLayers: convert EPSG:3006 to EPSG:4326

Tags: dictionary, coordinates, openlayers, projection, epsg

I'm trying to use a program that loads coordinates in EPSG:4326 format and plots on a map. The problem is that my coordinates are in EPSG:3006.

Is there any function to convert one projection in OpenLayers to another EPSG?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Projection in OpenLayers Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673945/change-projection-in-openlayers-map)

Answer (score 1):

The better way to do this is to use proj4js library [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/Download), it is simple and you can add custom projections if you want.

Below you can see how it works:

```
var SourceProjection= new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');
var DestinationProjections= new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3006');

var Point = new Proj4js.Point(longitude, latitude);          
Proj4js.transform(FirstProjection, SecondProjections, ne);
```

Or if you want to do it from openlayers you can use the "transform" function of geometry, here is a custom function that I use:

```
function TransformGeometry(geometry, SourceProj, DestProj) {
    geometry.transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection(SourceProj),
        new OpenLayers.Projection(DestProj));

    return geometry;
}
```

In any case you have to declare [proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/Download) in HTML tag in order to use a "long list" of projections (including here and custom projections you create).